# What does dollar sign means when inspecting an element?

Tags: google-chrome

Recently I noticed that when I inspect elements using Google Chrome, there is a "$" sign at the end of inspected element. What does this mean? Is there other values except 0? Should I consider something in codes?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0 is a reference to the selected element.
For example, if you type `jQuery($0).hide()` into the console, it will hide the element.  (assuming jQuery is included).

or you could do `console.log($1)` to log to the console the previous element that was selected (up to 4 in history ($1, $2, $3, $4).

[See Chrome's notes on the history](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#accessing-recently-selected-elements-and-objects)

Now to answer your question.
This could be useful for inspecting/debugging your website, but as it is only used in the console itself, other applications might be limited.